# Server-Client communication Java. Client freeze at function readObject()

Tags: java, server, client, data-transfer-objects

i write this code that should be a "comment section or review section" of an application.
i'm trying to send an ArrayList (commentcontent have just 2 string , user and comment, and implements Serializable). It seems that the server send the data to the client but at the moment of readObject() nothing happen and the code freeze like he still waiting something. Can someone help to solve this issue?

this is my server handler of the communications

```
public class CommentHandler extends Thread{


    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    
    public CommentHandler(Socket s) throws IOException {
        this.socket=s;
        this.out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            this.in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            while(true) {
                try {
                    String todo = (String )in.readObject();
                    sendMessage();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
            }
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void sendMessage() {
                try {
                    out.writeObject(new ArrayList<CommentContent>(DataBaseAccess.getInstance().getComments(13)));
                    out.flush();
                    System.out.println("SENT");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            
            //DataBaseAccess.getInstance().getComments(idGame);
        }
    }
```

and this is my client handler of the communications

```
public class CommentHandler {
    private static Socket socket;
    private static ObjectInputStream in;
    private static ObjectOutputStream out;
    
    public static void connect() throws Exception {

        if(socket!=null) return;

        socket= new Socket("localhost", 8000);
        out= new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }
    
    public static void read() throws Exception{
        if(socket==null) return;
        //sendRequest("todo");;
        if(in == null)
            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        
        //??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
        System.out.println("TRY TO RECEIVE");
        ArrayList<CommentContent> comm = new ArrayList<CommentContent>((ArrayList<CommentContent>) in.readObject()) ;

        System.out.println("RECEIVED");

    }
    
    public static void sendMessage(CommentContent message) throws Exception {
        if(out == null) return;
        out.writeObject(message);
        out.flush();
    }
    
    public static void sendRequest(String todo) throws IOException {
        if(out==null) return;
        out.writeObject(todo);
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

please Help.

PS. i call client.read() into the controller of my Pane and have a class Timer that refresh every sec the page.